# Grab from CSV, serialise selected fields and modify CSV

Tags: php, serialization, csv, macros

I have an Excel/CSV file with relatively simple format.

```
1|2|3|4|10|20|30
 | | | |40|50|60
 | | | |70|80|90
9|8|7|6|01|02|03
 | | | |04|05|06
 | | | |07|08|09
 | | | |10|11|12
```

The complete rows of 7 fields are single items, while the repeating columns of 5, 6 and 7 represent the data I want to serialise. Each main row can have any number of partial rows associated.

So for the above, item 1, the data to serialise is:

```
 | | | |10|20|30
 | | | |40|50|60
 | | | |70|80|90
```

Same for item 2, although the cell content is completely arbitrary, except for the number of items.

Output would be below to get the serialised data, except rather than print to page it needs to go back in to the CSV, as column 8, with the additional rows (2-3, 5-6 in this case) deleted.

If I can achieve the below, then it would be great:

```
<?
$line_1 = array(
    array('1' => '10', '20', '30'), 
    array('1' => '40', '50', '60'), 
    array('1' => '70', '80', '90'), 
);
$line_2 = array(
    array('1' => '01', '02', '03'), 
    array('1' => '04', '05', '06'), 
    array('1' => '07', '08', '09'), 
    array('1' => '10', '11', '12'), 
);
echo serialize($line_1);
echo serialize($line_2);
?>
```

So finally:

```
1|2|3|4|10|20|30|serialize($line_1)
9|8|7|6|01|02|03|serialize($line_2)
```

Then it would just be a case of getting it written to the parent line.

Output of the first line would be as follows and written to col H:

```
1|2|3|4|10|20|30|a:3:{i:0;a:3:{i:1;s:2:"10";i:2;s:2:"20";i:3;s:2:"30";}i:1;a:3:{i:1;s:2:"40";i:2;s:2:"50";i:3;s:2:"60";}i:2;a:3:{i:1;s:2:"70";i:2;s:2:"80";i:3;s:2:"90";}}
```

Is it possible to do that in Excel without PHP intervention, and if not how can it be done in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the question changed a bit, I'm going to give a new answer. Hope this helps.

```
<?php

  $array_to_serialize = array();
  $output_array = array();
  $in_lines = array();

  $in_csv = '1,2,3,4,10,20,30' . "\r\n" .
            ',,,,40,50,60' . "\r\n" .
            ',,,,70,80,90' . "\r\n" .
            '9,8,7,0,01,02,03' . "\r\n" .
            ',,,,40,11,60' . "\r\n" .
            ',,,,70,80,90' . "\r\n" .
            '9,8,7,6,01,02,03' . "\r\n" .
            ',,,,04,05,06' . "\r\n" .
            ',,,,07,08,09';


  $in_lines = explode("\n", $in_csv);

  while (list(, $line) = each($in_lines)) {

    $line_parts = explode(",", trim($line));

    if ($line_parts[0] != '') {

      if (!empty($beginning_numbers)) {
        $output_array[] = implode(',', $beginning_numbers) . ',' . serialize($matrix_part);
      }

      $beginning_numbers = array_slice($line_parts, 0, 4);
      $matrix_part = array(array_slice($line_parts, 4));

      $output_line = $line_parts;
      $array_to_serialize = array();
    } else {
      $matrix_part[] = array_slice($line_parts, 4);
    }

  }

  $output_array[] = implode(',', $beginning_numbers) . ',' . serialize($matrix_part);

  $out_text = implode("\r\n", $output_array);

  echo $out_text;

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

In excel, copy this line on h1:

```
=IF(A1<>"";IF(A2="";IF(A3="";TEXT(E2;"0")&","&TEXT(F2;"0")&","&TEXT(G2;"0")&","&TEXT(E3;"0")&","&TEXT(F3;"0")&","&TEXT(G3;"0");"");""); "")
```

then copy that line on the lines below it by dragging down from the lower right corner of the cell cursor.

if you want to do it in php, here's code for that (minus file reading):

```
<?php

  $array_to_serialize = array();
  $output_array = array();
  $in_lines = array();

  $in_csv = '1,2,3,4,10,20,30' . "\r\n" .
            ',,,,40,50,60' . "\r\n" .
            ',,,,70,80,90' . "\r\n" .
            '9,8,7,6,01,02,03' . "\r\n" .
            ',,,,04,05,06' . "\r\n" .
            ',,,,07,08,09';


  $in_lines = explode("\n", $in_csv);

  while (list(, $line) = each($in_lines)) {

    $line_parts = explode(",", trim($line));

    if ($line_parts[0] != '') {
      if (!empty($output_line)) {
        $output_array[] = implode(',', $output_line) . ',' . implode(',', $array_to_serialize);
      }

      $output_line = $line_parts;
      $array_to_serialize = array();
    } else {
      $array_to_serialize[] = $line_parts[4];
      $array_to_serialize[] = $line_parts[5];
      $array_to_serialize[] = $line_parts[6];
    }

  }

  $output_array[] = implode(',', $output_line) . ',' . implode(',', $array_to_serialize);

  $out_csv = implode("\r\n", $output_array);

  echo $out_csv;

?>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for taking the time to provide TWO solutions. I am going to work on the PHP as that's more flexible going forward, but the Excel formula generates an error - Excel doesn't like it?

Comment: Here's a link to an excel file with the example fully working: http://www.mediafire.com/?7b5d4rbu42rd3yi or http://www.megaupload.com/?d=2C1SZCG5 The file has sorting on the the cell A1 to demonstrate how to remove unneeded rows. If you copy and paste the whole page to a new excel sheet, you can get rid of the filtering with the data in the final stage. The excel method is always faster for one time quick data cleaning, but php is more flexible if you are doing it over and over again. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks again - not sure why ny local from scratch version did not work. I think it's going to have to be PHP for me, because the `serialize()` function in PHP produces a very different output to that of the excel, e.g. `a:2:{i:0;a:3:{i:1;s:3:"120";i:2;s:4:"12.5";i:3;s:8:"21-65-54";}i:1;a:3:{i:1;s:3:"122";i:2;s:2:"13";i:3;s:8:"21-65-54";}}` - I'm going to check out the PHP version now.

Comment: So I tried to PHP but it also outputs data like the Excel. I've updated the initial post to show the output I mean.

Comment: I've tried but I cannot get the PHP output to do what I need. I've updated the original question with a bit more detail.